# Complex multi module maven project failed to build

Tags: java, spring, maven, hexagonal-architecture

I stuck on building complex maven multi module project based on Hexagonal architecture.

My maven module structure look like that

```
|   graphql-intro (root module)
|   graphql-intro.xml
+-- bootloader (module)
|    +--- src/main/java/com/intro/graphql/ApplicationInitializer
|    +--- bootloader.xml
|
+-- domain (module)
|     +--- domain.xml
|
+-- infrastructure-adapters (module, root module for adapters)
|     +--- infrastructure-adapters.xml
|
|     +--- adapter-api-graphql (module)
|     |   +--- adapter-api-graphql.xml
|
|     +--- adapter-persistence-in-memory (module)
|     |   +--- adapter-persistence-in-memory.xml
|
|     +--- adapter-persistence-spring-data-jpa (module)
|     |   +--- adapter-persistence-spring-data-jpa.xml
```

root.xml look like that

```xml
    ...
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>domain</module>
        <module>infrastructure-adapters</module>
        <module>bootloader</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.into.graphql</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-into</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.intro.graphql.ApplicationInitializer</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
```

and this is infrastructure-adapters.xml

```xml
    <parent>
        <artifactId>graphql-into</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.into.graphql</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <artifactId>infrastructure-adapters</artifactId>
    <name>infrastructure-adapters</name>
    <description>infrastructure-adapters</description>

    <modules>
        <module>adapter-persistence-spring-data-jpa</module>
        <module>adapter-persistence-in-memory</module>
        <module>adapter-api-graphql-kickstarter</module>
    </modules>
```

The problem is that during build persistence adapters cannot see class from domain module, and this is pom in spring data jpa persistence adapter

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>com.into.graphql</groupId>
        <artifactId>infrastructure-adapters</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>adapter-persistence-spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <name>adapter-persistence-spring-data-jpa</name>
    <description>adapter-persistence-spring-data-jpa</description>

    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.into.graphql</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
```

The error is

```
[INFO] graphql-into ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.875 s]
[INFO] domain ............................................. SUCCESS [  2.582 s]
[INFO] infrastructure-adapters ............................ SUCCESS [  0.092 s]
[INFO] adapter-persistence-spring-data-jpa ................ FAILURE [  2.118 s]
[INFO] adapter-persistence-in-memory ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] adapter-api-graphql-kickstarter .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] bootloader ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.152 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-30T11:17:26+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project adapter-persistence-spring-data-jpa: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] path/graphql-into/infrastructure-adapters/adapter-persistence-spring-data-jpa/src/main/java/com/intro/graphql/persistance/jpa/products/ProductDaoAdapter.java:[3,33] package com.intro.grap
hql.dealers does not exist (it is package from domain module)
```

Has anyone know what could be a problem, can inside module depend from outside module or maybe the order of build is bad ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I moved build  configuration with `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to the bootloader pom and now build work. Unfortunatelly I dont know the reason why it solved problem.

Comment: I would need more info (modules dependencies, some source code, ...) for trying to find the reason, but of course spring boot mvn plugin must belong to the pom of the project with the main class.

Comment: Okay so the problem was that I configure spring boot mvn plugin in root pom not in pom with main class, so your comment explain the problem, thank you ;)